# How can I show that $|e^{2x} - e^{2y}| \leq 8|x - y|$ for all $x < y < \ln{2}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, absolute-value, mean-value-theorem

This is what I have managed to accomplish:

We consider the function $f(t) = e^{2t}$. Then, as $f$ is continuous on the real number line, it is continuous on $[x, y]$.

By the Mean Value Theorem,
$$
\exists c \in [x, y], \text{ such that } f'(c) = \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y - x}.
$$

That is,
$$
\exists c \in [x, y], \text{ such that } 2e^{2c} = \frac{e^{2y} - e^{2x}}{y - x}.
$$

As
$$
\frac{e^{2y} - e^{2x}}{y - x} = \frac{e^{2x} - e^{2y}}{x - y},
$$
we have
$$
\exists c \in [x, y], \text{ such that } 2e^{2c} = \frac{e^{2x} - e^{2y}}{x - y}.
$$

This is where I do not know how to continue.

1. How do I incorporate the absolute value signs into this equation?
2. How do I even substitute $\ln{c}$ into the equation? The question states that $x < y < \ln{2}$, so with $c \in [x, y]$, it is the case that $c \neq \ln{2}$. Could there be an error in the question?

I would greatly appreciate if anyone were to stumble by my question.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there! As $c\mapsto 2e^{2c}$ is an increasing function, it attains it maximum on $(-\infty,\ln 2]$ at $\ln2$, meaning also that $2e^{2c}\leq2e^{2\ln 2}$ for all $c<\ln 2$. You thus have that

$$\left\lvert\frac{e^{2y}-e^{2x}}{y-x}\right\rvert=\lvert 2e^{2c}\rvert\leq 2e^{2\ln 2}=8.$$

Rearranging we get

$$\lvert e^{2x}-e^{2y}\rvert\leq 8\lvert x-y\rvert.$$

Comment: Thank you Lorago. I appreciate your help.